# For some reason when I try signing the app for distribution I get a message saying it's private key is not installed

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I am trying to push an update to my Iphone app, which I managed to do fine a month and a half ago, but suddenly it gave me " has one Apple distribution certificate but its private key is not installed, contact the creator of this certificate to get a copy of the private key"

I tried looking up the problem, I deleted all of my certificates and revoked their licenses, created new ones did whatever. i can think of but still get this message. When I go to preferences -> accounts -> manage certificates, in "Apple distribution certificates" I can see the one I created, and. one grayed out certificate also created today saying "not in keychain"

I tried deleting them all and revoking them all, then adding through preferences -> account a distribution and development certificate, for some reason it creates one with the team name, grayed out saying "not in keychain", and one with no team name.

I tried looking all over, looking at other peoples posts, online, deleting and recreating, nothing worked. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Did you restart Xcode after recreating the certificates?

Comment: @Marcio I tried restarting my pc too.

Comment: Can you see the private key in `Keychain Access.app`?

Comment: @Marcio In Keychain Access.app I have a private key under my distribution certificate.

Comment: @dannyjayes1 have you solved it?